# Intel/AMD/ATOM Processor without support of Prefetching

Tags: performance, performance-testing, processor

I have two questions related to Processor .

1. What are the different Desktop Processor (I know one -Atom processor) which supports In-order execution   ?
2. Is there any processor which doesn't support H/W prefetching ?

In case, I want to check whether any available processor supports H/W prefetching or not, is there any flag available for that purpose ? Like msr is used to check in case of core2duo/core-i3 whether H/W prefetching is enabled or disabled ?

Any link will be great help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: re: part1: "supports in-order execution" sounds like hilarious marketing-speak for "doesn't support out-of-order execution".  I think Atom (not including Silvermont) is the only "modern" x86 design that doesn't do OOO.  The other low-power cores that Agner Fog's guide documents (AMD Bobcat/Jaguar, and Via Nano, and Intel Silvermont) are OOO.  Not as aggressively OOO as larger cores, of course, but still OOO.

Comment: @PeterCordes does Atom supports h/w prefetching ? or not ? I am trying to find a way to access 4KB data in a random order so that it is not detected and prefetched by H/w prefetcher if exist at all. Easy option to use a system where no h/w prefetcher exist. The other option is access the data in a random order to defeat the h/w prefetcher.

Comment: Agner Fog's microarch pdf says: "All caches have a
hardware prefetcher." (pg162, in the Atom section).  Existence of hw prefetch isn't mentioned for most other CPUs, but I'd be really surprised if at simple detection of sequential accesses wasn't done even in low-power CPUs, because it's essential for hiding memory latency in extremely common operations like `memcpy`.  See the [tag:x86] tag wiki for links.